# index out of range in lookup selection control

Tags: c#

i have a lookup control and button control
lookup control code is:-

```
private void  ViewlookupControl_SelectionControlMultiple(DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection vDataGrid)
{
    try
    {
        if (vDataGrid.Count > 0)
        {
            itemtxt.Tag = Convert.ToInt32(vDataGrid[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            itemtxt.Focus();
            clsDataV12 clsdata2 = new clsDataV12();
            SqlParameter[] sqlp4 = new SqlParameter[1];
            sqlp4[0] = new SqlParameter("@intAutoNo", Convert.ToInitemtxt.Tag.ToString()));
            DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
            dt4 = clsdata2.GetRecordsetParams("bomselectmaster", sqlp4);
            if (dt4.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt4.Rows[0];
                itemtxt.Text = ((dr["chrItemCode"] == System.DBNull.Value) ? "" : dr["chrItemCode"].ToString());
                definedtxt.Text = ((dr["numDefinedFor"] == System.DBNull.Value) ? "" : dr["numDefinedFor"].ToString());
                BOMdateTimePicker.Text = ((dr["dtmAppliFrom"] == System.DBNull.Value) ? "" : dr["dtmAppliFrom"].ToString());
            }
```

button control code is:-

```
case "View":
    try
    {
        ViewlookupControl.Visible = true;
        clsDataV12 clsdata1 = new clsDataV12();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = clsdata1.GetRecordset("bomview");
        ViewlookupControl.Fill(dt);
        ViewlookupControl.Focus();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        BOMbuttonControl.Action = false;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error");
    }
    break;
```

**the problem is when i select item in a lookup control it show index out of rang.must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.parameter name:index**

Comment: omg! that's a mess

Comment: If the problem is in the code you show, it will probably be this line `itemtxt.Tag = Convert.ToInt32(vDataGrid[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString());` - you don't do any boundary checking for `Cells[]` and this may be where you are exceeding the array bounds.

Comment: I think the problem is in the implementation of the method GetRecordSetParams, so we can help you more if you could show us it's implementation.

Comment: Obvious question - which line is throwing the exception??